# Kernel panic - not suncing: Attempted to kill init

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, centos6, panic

Today when I wake up my server was down after investigation I found out it was due to Kernel panic.

**The exact error:**

```
Kernel panic - not suncing: Attempted to kill init!
Pid: 1, comm: init Tainted: G       W  ---------------    2.6.32-431-29.2.e16.x86_64 #1
Call Trace:
[<ffffffff8152873c>] ? panic+0xa7/0x16f
[<ffffffff81077332>] ? do_exit+0x862/0xd0
[<ffffffff8118a805>] ? fput+0x25/0x30
[<ffffffff81077398>] ? do_group_exit+0x58/0xd0
[<ffffffff81077427>] ? sys_exit_group+0x17/0x20
[<ffffffff8100b072>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

I found other threads like: [How to solve "Kernel panic - not syncing - Attempted to kill init" -- without erasing any user data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867591/how-to-solve-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-without-er?newreg=6fc2203294fe43c8bcc03b8a702320a7) but all of them are different than mine.

All of getting a different error `Pid: 1, comm: init not Tainted` and mine is `Pid: 1, comm: init Tainted`

Comment: The kernel OOPS msg shared above is incomplete.