# access files on a broken xubuntu vm (or fix it)?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have Oracle Virtual Box running xubuntu. I wanted to install an ftp server so I typed:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

After a while I got a terminal popup asking HOW I wanted to remove phpmyadmin (wtf?). I didn't agree with that, so I pressed CTRL-C but that didn't help, so I selected the option to at least keep the phpmyadmin database. Then it continued but apparantly it remembered my CTRL-C and I got errors and things were broken.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

It mentioned cups. I googled cups and it something with printing and I don't need it. So I typed something like

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge cups cups-somethingelse cups-anothersomethingelse
```

Then it started to remove lots of programs, one of which was filezilla. I thought let's not panic, just let it finish. After it finished the upper bar of the OS was gone and it hang. After I shut it down externally it doesn't boot anymore :(. Did I fuck up?

The worst part is that I wanted to clone the vm this morning as a backup, but aborted that because it took too long.

edit: after a reboot of the host I now get this error when trying to boot:

```
end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attemted to kill init! exit code=0x00007f00
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to **access your files** would be

1. Detach the disk from the broken instance
2. Create a new instance with a new disk
3. Attach the old disk to the new instance

This way you shoulf be able to access the file system of the old disk.

About the kernel panic, there are many things that can lead to it. Try to check some hints in `/var/log/dmesg`. There you'll find the logs from the start up of the system. 
Try to see if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839356/3950497) helps you.